# Help! My phone becomes unbootable suddenly

Tags: samsung, boot-loop, crashes

It is Samsung Galaxy Note 2, unrooted.
I factory reset my phone to stock ROM about a week ago. Suddenly it became unbootable today. I didn't do anything risky. If my memory serves, I simply updated an app one day before this incident.

It always stuck at the Samsung Galaxy Note 2 logo screen.
I can boot to recovery mode and download mode.

The following errors displayed when I booted to recovery mode:

```
Android system recovery < 3e >
KOT49H.N7100ZSUFNL1

E:failed to mount /efs (No such file or directory)
E:failed to mount /system ((No such file or directory))

# MANUAL MODE #
--Appling Multi-CSC
E:failed to mount /system (No such file or directory)
can't mount '/system' (No such file or directory)
E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
can't mount '/cache' (No such file or directory)
E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
E:can't mount /cache/recovery/last_recovery
E:failed to mount /data (No such file or directory)
E:can't mount /data/log/recovery_log.txt
E:failed to mount /system (No such file or directory)
E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
E:can't mount /cache/recovery/log
E:can't open /cache/recovery/log
E:failed to mount cache (No such file or recovery)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_log
E:can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or recovery)
E:can't mount /cache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_install
E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or recovery)
```

I tried to wipe cache partition. It didn't help.

How could I backup data in this case?
I just need to get back my photos.

How could I fix and restore my phone?

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you got a Windows powered computer, an USB to MicroUSB cable and a void warranty?

Comment: Something wrong with the eMMC chip, this may have happened while charging your phone with a wall charger(happened to my N8000 tablet months ago). You need to repair the bootloader (sboot).

Comment: @esQmo Just a corrupted PIT or a whole fried chip, you say?

Comment: I won't say the whole since he can still boot in recovery, on mine i had only download mode.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Yes I have all of them. I don't mind if I void the warranty. It is expired anyway.
I tried to connect it to the Windows computer. The device didn't show up at all. Windows recognized it with errors in Device Manager.

Comment: @esQmo It was suddenly unbootable when the phone was on and idle. I didn't charge the phone at that time.

I would like to try my best to backup the photos before I do any hard reset or reflashing.
I would highly appreciate any workaround or method. Thanks.

Comment: Flashing a custom recovery can help backup all your data. And if your phone is not recognized by the computer, you need to install drivers.

Comment: @esQmo Which custom recovery should I use? I haven't tried before. Please give me directions. The phone could be recognized by the computer before the incident. After that I installed Samsung USB Driver. It can be recognized but with errors.

Comment: You should try TWRP recovery for your device model. Choose the Odin install method as it does not require root (https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxynote2n7100.html)

Comment: TWRP has many more features than stock recovery, such as making full NAND backups, flashing zips through recovery, ADB sideload, and more! Plus, if something goes wrong while flashing something, you can always restore from a backup using TWRP, meaning you're much safer when flashing new ROM's, etc.

Comment: @esQmo Will all my photos be deleted if I use TWRP recovery?

Comment: On phone with locked bootloader yes because you need to unlock it first and this wipes all data on the phone. From my experience, youou can flash only the recovery (with Odin) this doesn't wipe data.

Comment: @esQmo How can I flash only the recovery (with Odin) without wiping data? I've never done this. I'm afraid I do it wrong. Please give me instructions. Thank you.

Comment: I provided you the complete guide. Download the recovery, open Odin, click on PDG, load the download recovery, put your phone in download mode, connect ot to the computer, click on start. When you see PASS you're done. Boot in recovery (Volume up + Power)

Comment: @esQmo It failed. I installed SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones. 
I downloaded Odin3 v3.12. 
I downloaded twrp-3.0.2-0-t03g.img.tar and twrp-2.8.7.0-t03g.img.tar. 
I ran Odin3 v3.12 with admin privilege. 
I chose "AP" and selected "twrp-3.0.2-0-t03g.img.tar"
I connected the phone and pressed "Start". The error message: https://justpaste.it/11ai3

Comment: I tried twrp-2.8.7.0-t03g.img.tar too but still got the same error. Please help.

Comment: What is your phone model number?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you cant get your photo back. Try to flashing your phone with odin. Its work for me with samsung galaxy s4 later month ago.

There is file system that missing in your android rom, and you should flashing it.

Comment: That sucks. I hope there is still a way to get back the photos. I don't want to flash the ROM now.
Is it possible to fix the firmware while keeping the photos intact?